# What's the probability distribution of a deterministic signal or how to marginalize dynamical systems? (functional integrals in probability theory)

Tags: probability, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, ergodic-theory

In many signal processing calculations, the (prior) probability distribution of the theoretical signal (not the signal + noise) is required.

In random signal theory, this distribution is typically a stochastic process, e.g. a Gaussian or a uniform process.

What do such distributions become in deterministic signal theory?, that is the question.

To make it simple, consider a discrete-time real deterministic signal

$ s\left( {1} \right),s\left( {2} \right),...,s\left( {M} \right) $

For instance, they may be samples from a continuous-time real deterministic signal.

By the standard definition of a discrete-time deterministic dynamical system, there exists:

- a phase space $\Gamma$, e.g. $\Gamma  \subset  \mathbb{R} {^d}$
- an initial condition $ z\left( 1 \right)\in \Gamma $
- a state-space equation $f:\Gamma  \to \Gamma $ having $ z\left( 1 \right)$ in its domain of definition such as $z\left( {m + 1} \right) = f\left[ {z\left( m \right)} \right]$
- an output or observation equation $g:\Gamma  \to \mathbb{R}$ such as $s\left( m \right) = g\left[ {z\left( m \right)} \right]$

Hence, by definition we have

$\left[ {s\left( 1 \right),s\left( 2 \right),...,s\left( M \right)} \right] = \left\{ {g\left[ {z\left( 1 \right)} \right],g\left[ {f\left( {z\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right],...,g\left[ {{f^{M - 1}}\left( {z\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right]} \right\}$

or, in probabilistic notations

$p\left[ {\left. {s\left( 1 \right),s\left( 2 \right),...,s\left( M \right)} \right|z\left( 1 \right),f,g,\Gamma ,d} \right] = \prod\limits_{m = 1}^M {\delta \left\{ {g\left[ {{f^{m - 1}}\left( {z\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right] - s\left( m \right)} \right\}} $

Therefore, by total probability and the product rule, the marginal joint prior probability distribution for a discrete-time deterministic signal conditional on phase space $\Gamma$ and its dimension $d$ formally/symbolically writes

$p\left[ {\left. {s\left( 1 \right),s\left( 2 \right),...,s\left( M \right)} \right|\Gamma ,d} \right] = \int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^\Gamma }} {{\text{D}}g\int\limits_{{\Gamma ^\Gamma }} {{\text{D}}f\int\limits_\Gamma  {{{\text{d}}^d}z\left( 1 \right)\prod\limits_{m = 1}^M {\delta \left\{ {g\left[ {{f^{m - 1}}\left( {z\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right] - s\left( m \right)} \right\}p\left( {z\left( 1 \right),f,g} \right)} } } } $

Should phase space $\Gamma$ and its dimension $d$ be also unknown *a priori*, they should be marginalized as well so that the most general marginal prior probability distribution for a deterministic signal I'm interested in formally/symbolically writes

$p\left[ {s\left( 1 \right),s\left( 2 \right),...,s\left( M \right)} \right] = \sum\limits_{d = 2}^{ + \infty } {\int\limits_{\wp \left( {{\mathbb{R}^d}} \right)} {{\text{D}}\Gamma \int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^\Gamma }} {{\text{D}}g\int\limits_{{\Gamma ^\Gamma }} {{\text{D}}f\int\limits_\Gamma  {{{\text{d}}^d}z\left( 1 \right)\prod\limits_{m = 1}^M {\delta \left\{ {g\left[ {{f^{m - 1}}\left( {z\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right] - s\left( m \right)} \right\}p\left( {z\left( 1 \right),f,g,\Gamma ,d} \right)} } } } } } $

where ${\wp \left( {{\mathbb{R}^d}} \right)}$ stands for the powerset of ${{\mathbb{R}^d}}$.

Dirac's $\delta$ distributions are certainly welcome to "digest" those very high dimensional integrals. However, we may also be interested in probability distributions like

$p\left[ {s\left( 1 \right),s\left( 2 \right),...,s\left( M \right)} \right] \propto \sum\limits_{d = 2}^{ + \infty } {\int\limits_{\wp \left( {{\mathbb{R}^d}} \right)} {{\text{D}}\Gamma \int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^\Gamma }} {{\text{D}}g\int\limits_{{\Gamma ^\Gamma }} {{\text{D}}f\int\limits_\Gamma  {{{\text{d}}^d}z\left( 1 \right)\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^ + }} {{\text{d}}\sigma {\sigma ^{ - M}}{e^{ - \sum\limits_{m = 1}^M {\frac{{{{\left\{ {g\left[ {{f^{m - 1}}\left( {z\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right] - s\left( m \right)} \right\}}^2}}}{{2{\sigma ^2}}}} }}p\left( {\sigma ,z\left( 1 \right),f,g,\Gamma ,d} \right)} } } } } } $

Please, what can you say about those important probability distributions beyond the fact that they should not be invariant by permutation of the time points, i.e. not De Finetti-exchangeable?

What can you say about such strange looking functional integrals (for the state-space and output equations $f$ and $g$) and even set-theoretic integrals (for phase space $\Gamma$) over sets having cardinal at least ${\beth_2}$? Are they already well-known in some branch of mathematics I do not know yet or are they only abstract nonsense?

More generally, I'd like to learn more about functional integrals in probability theory. Any pointer would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question, in signal processing we choose a model for the signal, if the model is probalistic then we can think in term of probability distribution. what do you want to say more ?

Comment: In classical, random signal theory (à la Shannon), the signal is supposed to be stochastic. For instance, if the samples are i.i.d., the distribution of the signal is the product distribution. Here I'm considering deterministic signals coming from some dynamical system. By definition (Cauchy's problem), the signal is entirely determined by initial condition z1. That's a completely different situation, hence the question.

Comment: yes, and if you want to use probabilities, you'll have to choose a probabilistic model for your deterministic signal, what we often do in signal processing.

Comment: what I mean is that once the probabilistic model is chosen, the situation becomes exactly the same as for a stochastic process/signal : the deterministic signal is no longer seen as deterministic ..

Comment: The problem is precisely how to go from the first, conditional model to the second, marginal, unconditional, average model, i.e. how to marginalize the state-space equation (= the underlying dynamical system) and the output equation. Given f and g, the problem is "just" ergodic theory (Perron-Frobenius operator, invariant measures, etc.).

Comment: In other words: how to marginalize a dynamical system?

Comment: what ? assuming $(X_n)$ is i.i.d. then $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{E}[X_n]$ and assuming $(x_n)$ is a realization of $(X_n)$ then $\mathbb{E}[X_n] \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N x_n$. everything is about the model : it is the model which defines how you'll be able to estimate its parameters from its realizations ( the signal(s)).

Comment: and it is not because the signal is deterministic that it has to be the realization of some deterministic dynamical system, it's like if you were messing up everything. are you interested only in that dynamical system case ?

Comment: I don't mess anything. I'm considering some output signal from a dynamical system, the probability distribution of which is entirely determined by the probability distribution of initial condition z1, given f and g. Then I'm considering the case where f and g also have a prior probability distribution and ask again for the (marginal) probability distribution of the signal. It is supposed to be a research level question but I'm not really sure and it's still unanswered: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/232043/whats-the-probability-distribution-of-a-deterministic-signal-functional-integ

Comment: ok then this comment is much more well explained than your question : the model isn't deterministic, only $X_n | (X_{m})_{m < n}$ is deterministic, but the initial conditions $(X_n)_{n \le 0}$ are random variables, and so is $X_n$

Comment: and the case where $X_n | (X_{n-a})_{a > 0}$ is some linear function independent of $n$ is the simplest case and is very well studied : it is a LTI process

Comment: Here zn/zn-1 is the  Dirac distribution Delta(zn-f(zn-1)) and z1 has some distribution in the phase-space. The problem is with the double functional integral in the last equation. How to compute it, that is the question.

Comment: you didn't understand yet that your question is way too general : on the general case there is nearly nothing to say, but there are dozen of techniques / books detailing some particular cases. so give what is for you an interesting example and you'll get much more answers (its like if you wanted to merge together LTI systems, HMM, Kalman filters, ....)

Comment: I fear I understand my question. There are only two degrees of freedom: the phase-space and the prior probability distribution p(z1,f,g). So fix a phase-space/d and such a prior distribution, e.g. the uniform distribution, PROVIDED IT CAN BE DEFINED because we are dealing with probability distributions over functional spaces. That's the point. Then, please do compute the probability distribution of the signal according to the last equation. Of course, you may partition the set of the dynamical systems into suitable subsets if necessary, e.g. linear, nonlinear, chaotic, ergodic systems, etc.

Comment: Would f and g be normal, usual random variables, my question would not only be perfectly well-posed: it would be trivial, the required probability distribution being obtained by basic, standard integration. But and f and g are functions so that my question is about probability theory way beyond measure theory.